# How can I sync files that aren't tracked by git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a project on Github. There's a "config.js" file with some config values (such as passwords) that is not in github (i.e., it is listed in the ".gitignore" file).

So, how can I keep that config.js file synced between computers? I could use Dropbox, but I'll still have to remember every time I open up the project to check whether the file I have on my computer is the most updated version - is there a better way? What are best practices for shared coding projects?

Comment: what OS are you running

Comment: Best practice is to obviously not add the config files containing passwords and sensitive stuff to the git repository, If many people are working on the same project it is always better for each person to have a separate config file with a separate username password. Under no circumstances do you want to share your sensistive data in a git repository.

Comment: One thing you could do is have a git filter that keeps the committed content encrypted in the repo..

Comment: @NullSoulException, I'm using Windows 10 on two separate computers.

Comment: @noel-zubin, I figured that. I was asking about best practices for syncing files that aren't tracked by git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an open source project, you don't want to add it to Git if it has passwords.

But, you do need the file. The question is, do you need it for deployment or for development?

If you only need the file for deployment, depending on what you are using to deploy you can use Environment Variables. For instance, on Travis you can set $SOME_VALUE to replace with your secret info, but anybody downloading the code would only see $SOME_VALUE.

However, that might not work depending on what your deployment is (or if you need the file for testing/dev)

Then it comes down to: You need to have a private Git repo (Pay on GitHub, or use a service like Visual Studio Team Services or BitBucket to get a free private repo) so that you can commit files you want to share to the whole team. Or, you can host it in some other secure location and then have instructions for team members to download the file separately as you said.

Which is not ideal for ease of use, but multiple steps will have to be involved unless you use a private repo.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to build my portfolio, so I'd prefer not to make my repos private unless I have to. I guess I'll stick to using Dropbox to sync the file, even though it's a bit of extra work.